# Do we ever find out what Chow Chu's power is?

Tags: comics, image-comics, chew

I've recently finally finished reading Chew, and in one of the issues (~issue 35) Toni and one of the other Chu sisters are commiserating about the various powers. It's the only time that it's mentioned that apparently all of the Chu siblings have food-related powers. The two of them start to laugh and say well, at least they don't have Chow's power. I didn't re-read the earlier issues, just picked up where I left off, but I don't remember Chow's power ever being mentioned. The best I can guess is that he can make any ingredients delicious, but that's just a guess. Do we ever find out, either in-universe or out-of-universe, what Chow's power are, and if so what are they?